# Spawning Enemy at a Random Location

Tags: iphone, random, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, spawning

I've been following this code snippet from Ray Wenderlich's tutorials (http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1d8b). I'm trying to do almost the same thing, except I'm using a spritesheet (batchnode), and I want the targets/enemies to spawn from the right side of the screen (at any height), and move to the left side (at the same height). Here is my code. (http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1d8c).

Extra info - "moles" are my targets/enemies. Commented out code (//) beside the first few lines are just my notes.
EDIT - Look at my comment on mjvotaw's answer.

Comment: There's no errors or crashing, but the enemies spawn from the bottom left corner, and then go to ccp:(100, 100). They spawn from the wrong place. Also, they all spawn at the exact same place of that corner. It's not randomized.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the [links to codeviewer.org no longer work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345443/what-should-happen-to-questions-using-codeviewer-org-for-sharing-code). Without these links, the question has no clear [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place your mole sprite in a random spot along the right side, you should be able to just do:

```
[mole setPosition: ccp(winSize.width - [mole contentSize].width, arc4random() % winSize.height)];
```

That sets the mole at the far right edge, at a random spot along the y axis.
Then, instead of actionMove using CCMoveTo, you can just use CCMoveBy, setting the position to ccp(-winSize.width, 0).

If this isn't what you're looking for, perhaps you should rethink how to ask your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code up a bit (http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1d91). When I run I get the enemy flashing on the position I want it to be at, but then switches locations to the bottom of the screen again. Is there something wrong with my code? Please check, thanks.

Comment: I noticed you set the mole's position on line 6, but you don't actually create the mole object until like 19, don't know how I didn't catch that before. You shouldn't be referencing the mole object before you create the CCSprite.

Comment: THANKS so much! You don't know how much you've helped me out =D

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) on creating enemies that move toward a target starting from a random point. It's a little ways down the page.

EDIT:

To create a random Y spawn point, do the following: (Assuming that you're using cocos2d)

```
// Define these at the top of the .m file
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000
#define RAND_FLOAT ( (float)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX )

- (CGPoint)pointWithRandomYAtX:(float)locationX
{
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    return CGPointMake(locationX, RAND_FLOAT * size.height);
}
```

Then simply set the position of the "mole" to that point.

Comment: That's the exact same tutorial I took the snippet from, and that's not my question. I know how/where I want to move the enemy, but the original spawning location is giving me trouble.

Comment: When I do that, the enemies spawn in the bottom left corner (wrong place), and then go off the screen to the left. When a new one spawns, an enemy flashes in a different/random location along the left side of the screen (what I want, except that it only flashes there for a split second, and I want it to be on the right side of the screen). Could you take a look at this file? It's my .m. Thanks
http://www.4shared.com/file/zY8LSBiW/Mole.html
The code is in the addMole method.